# How to create object from String?

Tags: php

I tried the code below:

```
$dyn = "new ". $className . "(" .$param1 . ", ". $param2 . ");";
$obj = eval($dyn);
```

It compiles but it's null.

How can you instance object in PHP dynamicaly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$class = 'ClassName';
$obj = new $class($arg1, $arg2);
```

Comment: what if class name in static property?   `class From { static $toCreate='ClassName';}`

Comment: I believe doing `new From::$toCreate()` should still work... If not then you would just assign it to var before instantiation.

Comment: its not exactly what I meant. We have class `class From { static $toCreate='ClassName'; public static function some(){};}`. We need to call static method `some`, and it should have syntax like `Form::$toCreate::some()`. Ofcourse,  it wouldnt work. But we can like `$dynName=Form::$toCreate; $dynName::some()` and it will work. But this is not much perfect (

Answer (score 4):

If you *really* want to use `eval` - which chances are you shouldn't if you're this new to PHP ;) - you'd do something more like...

```
$dyn = "new ". $className . "(" .$param1 . ", ". $param2 . ");";
eval("\$obj = $dyn");
```

Comment: Just because someone is starting to learn a language, it doesn't necessarily mean they have no experience programming.. but it's a fair warning for new developers :)=

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually trying to accomplish? eval would work, but its probably not a very good idea.

What you might want to do is implement a [factory](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php) for your objects that take a string defining what class to load, and an optional array for the constructors parameters