# Yii2 Override Rest Api actioncreate method

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

can anyone tell me how to override actioncreate and actionupdate method yii2 rest api..

```
class CabController extends ActiveController
  {
     public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\Cab';

      public function actions(){

        $actions = parent::actions();           

        unset($actions['create']);
        unset($actions['update']);

        return $actions;
    }

     public function actionCreate(){

        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        $model = $this->modelClass;
       $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
       $cur_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       $model->date_created  =  $cur_time;
       $$model->save(false);
  }
```

If i do like this mean i got error like 500 internal server error and error message like Call to a member function load() on a non-object ..how to solve this issue..
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating object, instead you are assigning string `api\modules\v1\models\Cab` to `$model` variable. Change assigning part to:

```
$model = new $this->modelClass;
```

In case of "Class not found" error add leading backslash to class name: `\api\modules\v1\models\Cab`.

Related answers about creating object from string:

- [Creating PHP class instance with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578335/creating-php-class-instance-with-a-string)
- [Dynamically create PHP object based on string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201335/dynamically-create-php-object-based-on-string)
- [How to create object from String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079911/how-to-create-object-from-string)